# How to disable script for a link?

Tags: javascript

I have the link on the page https://distancework.eu/en/register/guest/register.html?step=3 which opens a document with Terms and conditions. After clicking this link(image1) the modal window will be opened. This window doesn't have a scrolling. I decide to disable this modal window. I created a new page with Terms and conditions and inserted the url of the page to html code(see image2). And when I disable the javascript in the browser it doesn't open the modal window but opens the correct page. How I can to disable script which opens this modal window?

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kEwx.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81rnQ.jpg)

Files that are related to the modal window:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v5U1Dhd03Q_0E0Tbt415YHShe6i9CBp0/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JdbsjYybDpo_D7UZXPdrrhJNxz7Wdvek/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

use `void` to disable script, `href="javascript:void(0)"` in your link